# Why can't I change list-style in css (OpenCart)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm not able to affect the list-style in my website through CSS. The "bullets" disappeared from my lists all of a sudden and there is nothing in my CSS file that would disable them.

For example here is a product page: http://www.azores-store.com/rollup/rollup-85cm/roll-up-premium-85

The list starts from "nykyaikainen muotoilu". If you look at the source code of the page you can see that the ul and li tags don't have any attributes, they are just defaults.

Now if you look at the CSS file: http://www.azores-store.com/catalog/view/theme/adefault2/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

There's nothing that would disable the bullets from the lists. I have tried referring to the list with a class but it has no effect.

I'm really confused here... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A question should contain sufficient code to reproduce the problem. Links are *not* enough, especially when they point to live pages: the question becomes meaningless after the pages have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to remember that if I need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the padding removal. By default, lists have a `40px` `padding-left` value.
 If you remove the `ul, ul li{/* list-style: none; */}` from your css, and give the `ul` some padding-left value, you will see the disc.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added 40px padding-left and it moved the lists from the left but still no discs.

Comment: add `list-style-position:inside` and check if it is ok

Comment: You're welcome! Also please mark the answer as the solution, to close it

Comment: Hmm... I have actually the same problem on a different page: http://www.azores-store.com/rekisteriseloste

I applied the same styles for this page also and the padding works but the discs are not visible :/

Comment: File "dcaccordions.css" line 3 remove `ul, ul li{/* list-style: none; */}` on line 3

Comment: I see, thanks. I didn't even know that CSS file existed because it was part of an extension.